# Реализация класса с таймером и управление им ( Swift )

Tags: swift, post, view, таймер

Вопрос по структуре, как она должна выглядеть, когда стоит такая задача:

Есть 5шт ViewContoller. Некоторые выводят состояние устройства, с которым идет общение по пост запросу, некоторые решают другие задачи, но например при вызове аллерта из метода в таймере, он должен показываться по всему приложению.
Нужно что бы этот запрос повторялся каждые 4 секунды и обновлял всю информацию на всех контроллерах, которые выводят результаты. В определенных условиях, из этих 5и контроллеров, таймер нужно останавливать и так же и запускать (например ЛогИн/ЛогАут и тд).

Как должен выглядеть этот виртуальный класс с таймером и запросом и как управлять таймером с других классов? и верный ли вообще подход?

Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ - реализовать функцию, которая будет отсылать запрос каждые четыре секунды в AppDelegate (или в отдельном классе). А при получении ответа от сервера отправлять нотификацию для UIViewContoller-ов. Контроллеры при показе экрана (viewDidAppear) подписываются на эту нотификацию, а при закрытии (viewDidDisappear) - отписываются от нотификации. Для отключения таймера можете тоже отправить нотификацию (уже в ваш класс) или просто установить переменную, например allowUpdateTimer в false прямо из UIViewContoller-а и проверяйте ее состояние (в вашем классе) перед обращением к серверу.

Если данные реально обновляются не каждые 4 секунды, а например раз в несколько минут, есть смысл использовать нотификацию через Firebase Cloud Messaging или открывать и держать WebSocket. Приложение станет тратить меньше батареи.

---

ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ:

Я сделал простой пример:

В AppDelegate создаем таймер, делаем чтобы он каждые 4 секунды вызывал функцию получения времени с сервера. Ответ сервера отправляет нотификацию по имени update_new_date.

Файл AppDelegate.swift

```
var timer: Timer?
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4, target:self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.update_data), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    return true
}
func update_data()
{
    Alamofire.request("https://time.is/Moscow").responseJSON { response in
        if let contentType = response.response?.allHeaderFields["Expires"] as? String {
            print("Date: \(contentType)")
            let dataDict:[String: String] = ["date": contentType]
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("update_new_date"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
        }
    }
}
```

На эту нотификацию мы подписываемся при показе UIViewController-ов:

Файлы UIViewController-ов:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(update_new_date(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("update_new_date"), object: nil)
}
```

Пришедшая нотификация вызывает функцию обновления данных на экране:

```
func update_new_date(notification: Notification){
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo as? [String: Any]
    {
        if let date = userInfo["date"] as? String {
            time_label.text = date
            appDelegate.animate_update(view: time_label)
        }
    }
}
```

Когда экран перестает отображаться, отписываемся от нотификаций:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Таймер вы можете остановить откуда угодно, обратившись к AppDelegate:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.timer?.invalidate()
```

И запустить дальше:

```
appDelegate.timer?.fire()
```

---

[image: Пример автоматически обновляемых данных]

Полная версия примера: [Github](https://github.com/nightsilf/ExampleTimerUpdate)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, долго ждал кого-то) Итак, я понял все так: 1.Создаю класс с функцией таймера и запроса. 2.Cтарую ее из appDelegate используя .post(...), там принимаю и стартую 3. При успешном ответе делаю .post(...) 4. в контроллере, в котором я нахожусь во viewDidAppear создается приемник .addObserver(...) вызывающий определенные методы 5. при уходе из этого контроллера я должен отписаться от приема во viewDidDisappear или в deinit, .remove(self).

Comment: Я немного не понимаю какие именно нужны методы , так как есть post NSnotification.name, а есть с прописыванием своего имени .postNotificationName(...) какой мне нужен, или это не важно?
И все ли верно, что я перечислил в первом комментарии? 
(по символам не влез)
Спасибо

Comment: Я добавил пример в ответ. Пишите если будет непонятно.

Comment: Замечательный подробный ответ, есть только вопрос, как правильно обращаться к таймеру, если я его реализовал в отдельном классе(Utilits), а не в ЭпДелегате? Или просто создавать в каждом котроллере новый экземпляр класса `let update_data = Utilits()` ? Просто тогда это не управление одним и тем же таймером, а каждый раз новым

Comment: Используйте Singleton для доступа к единственному экземпляру Utilits.

Comment: Все стало на свои места, все ваши советы применил и получил желаемый результат! Спасибо